# PHP foreach SQL INSERT

Tags: php, sql, post, foreach

I am trying to create a loop that will get the data from the form(fields created dynamically). Then on each loop submit that group of fields to a new row in the database. I have the following code for the loop.

It doesn't give out any errors, it just does not add to the database. I tried a simplified version without the loop and [$key],it worked and added one row. So I know the connection to the database is fine and working.

The fields with [$key] are the dynamically created fields. Any help on fixing this code would be appreciated.

Thanks!
MM

**SQL QUERY:**

```
    foreach($_POST['itemNameData'] as $key => $val)
          {
   //Data from dynamic form fields
   $fields[] = array(
      'itemNameData' =>$_POST['itemNameData'] [$key],
      'itemHref' =>$_POST['itemHref'] [$key],
      'itemImg' =>$_POST['itemImg'] [$key],
      'itemPrice' =>$_POST['itemPrice'] [$key] );

    //Data fields not in form
       $userId = "username";
       $userIp = "127.0.0.1";
       $itemSite = "1";
       $itemType = "shirt";
       $success = "yes";

    /**** INSERT data ****/
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userItems   (userId,itemHref,itemImg,itemPrice,itemNameData,userIp,itemSite,itemType) VALUES (:userId,:itemHref,:itemImg,:itemPrice,:itemNameData,:userIp,:itemSite,:itemType)";
      $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute(array(':userId'=>$userId,
                         ':itemHref'=>$itemHref[$key],
                         ':itemImg'=>$itemImg[$key],
                         ':itemPrice'=>$itemPrice[$key],
                         ':itemNameData'=>$itemNameData[$key],
                         ':userIp'=>$userIp,
                         ':itemSite'=>$itemSite,
                         ':itemType'=>$itemType));

      }
```

Comment: Not should be `':itemImg' => $fields['itemImg']` for example? ;)

Comment: If you mean like this:                                                 $q ->execute(array(':itemImg=> $fields['itemImg'] I tried but it still did not insert into the database. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not only for itemImg... but, you can check the values that you send to execute? Something like:

`print_r(array(':userId'=>$userId,
                         ':itemHref'=>$itemHref[$key],
                         ':itemImg'=>$itemImg[$key],
                         ':itemPrice'=>$itemPrice[$key],
                         ':itemNameData'=>$itemNameData[$key],
                         ':userIp'=>$userIp,
                         ':itemSite'=>$itemSite,
                         ':itemType'=>$itemType)); `